# Changing multiple elements' styles with a same class name at once with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of divs with different combinations of classes in each (e.g. "a A", "a b", "b A", "b" etc.).

With a press of a button, I need to change the styles of, for example, all elements which have the class A (not only 'A', but must include it. E.g. both "d A" and "A" would work)

I have tried

> document.getElementsByClassName('a A').style.background = "#f00";

but it didn't work. The console says that it can't set a style for element 'undefined', so I guess it doesn't get what I need with `getElementsByClassName();`.

Comment: Get [jQuery](http://jquery.com/): `$('.A,.a').css('background', '#f00');`

Comment: Greetings! I am from the future and have come here to let you know about querySelectorAll: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DOM methods that `getElementsBySomething` (plural), as opposed to ones which `getElementBySomething` return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NodeList), not an element. NodeLists are Array-like objects.

You have to loop over it and change each element in turn if you take that approach. Most libraries have shortcut methods to do that for you.

e.g. for YUI 3:

```
Y.all('.foo').setStyle('background', '#f00');
```

or jQuery

```
jQuery('.foo').css('background', '#f00');
```

An alternative approach would be to modify [the stylesheet itself with JavaScript](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html).

A third option would be to set up your changed styles in advance, using a descendent selector such as:

```
.foo { /* something */ }
body.bar .foo { /* something else */ }
```

And then

```
document.body.className += " bar";
```

to activate the alternative styling.

Comment: Thank you. I am using jQuery already for some other stuff on the page. This works, so, thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

You should try using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) that allows you to use CSS selectors. Then you would be able to do

```
$('.a,.A').css("background", "#f00");
```

You could even change multiple styles at once with multiple elements

```
$('.a,.A').css({"background": "#f00", "color": "#000"});
```